# Refreshing the ui after changes in com port availability

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, com-port

I've written a C# .NET 5 application that needs to notify the application user when a serial port resource is available in the system. Currently, the user has to push a refresh button so that all currently available serial ports are listed in the UI (by calling the static method GetPortNames of the SerialPort class). But I'd like the system to automatically inform the user about changes in port availability. Is there someway to do it in .NET? I'm thinking about something akin to FileSystemWatcher. For example, an event handler that is invoked when a COM port becomes available/unavailable? And if this couldn't be done with a managed code solution, then could it be achieved using P/Invoke or something.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using a Windows Form Application. In this case, you need to keep the reference of the Windows Form you want to update. You can keep this reference for this object wherever you want.

Remember, if you are running your Serial Port on another thread, it cannot modify the elements on the form, because only the UI Thread can do this.

An easier way to modify UI Elements on the UI Thread is by calling the Inkove method:

```
form.Invoke(... reference to the method)
```